# Biblatex - verbose-trad1 order of names in references

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with style `verbose-trad1` because it is the most appropriate one for preferences of my alma mater, but it doesn't fit in with one thing:
it is required that citations in footnotes should start with abbreviation of author's first name and then last name, whilst in references there should be last name and then first name.

Do You know how to make it work in `verbose-trad1` style? Here are my current settings. I would really appreciate Your help!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
defernumbers=true,
backend=bibtex8, 
style=verbose-trad1,%verbose-ibid,
bibstyle=numeric,
firstinits=true,
sorting=nty,
isbn=false,
abbreviate = false,]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
  @book{example1,
    author={{Archibald Kandinsky}},
    title={Archies first report}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\begin{document}
  aaa\footcite{example1}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double braces in `author={{Archibald Kandinsky}},` cause `biblatex` (actually Biber or BibTeX) to treat `Archibald Kandinsky` as a single unit and not a the name of a person with given name *Archibald* and family name *Kandinsky*. So no matter what else we do, one pair of braces has to go, the input must be of the form

```
@book{example1,
  author = {Archibald Kandinsky},
  title  = {Archies first report}
}
```

In the MWE you are mixing `verbose-trad1` with a `numeric` bibliography. That makes little sense because the numbers in the bibliography will have no connection with anything else in the document. I suggest you go for a pure `verbose-trad1` solution, in which case you would need

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex8, 
style=verbose-trad1,
isbn=false,
abbreviate = false,]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}% family given in bibliography

\AtEveryCitekey{\toggletrue{abx@bool@giveninits}}% initials in citations

\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}% if you want subsequent citations with initials as well

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{example1,
  author = {Archibald Kandinsky},
  title  = {Archies first report}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem\autocite{example1} ipsum\autocite{sigfridsson} dolor\autocite{example1}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Fn 1 A. Kandinsky. Archies first report.//Fn 2 E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pages 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//Fn 3 A. Kandinsky, op. cit.]

If you for some reason have to stick to your combination of `numeric` and `verbose-trad1` (don't! at best it adds irrelevant information and distracts, at worst it causes confusion because people think footnote numbers and the numbers in the bibliography are related) you will also need the three lines

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
```